# How to change adsense ads location with javascript?

Tags: javascript, adsense

What i am trying to accomplish is what the guy says in an [adsense optimisation video at 8:04](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UbxiBZtqDM#t=8m4s)
.

I want to change the ad code position on the page, not the ad display.

Hope you understand what I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What he means is you need to have your most clicked on ads show up first in your html because they are higher paying. JavaScript isn't going to help you there, you need to arrange your layout and/or css if getting the ad in the correct position is important to you.

Comment: Yes Andy, but if there is a way javascript works (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UbxiBZtqDM#t=8m20s), i want to find it, because layout/css is't to convenient in my case.